# Static IP changes to dynamic automatically after time

Tags: debian, networking, ip, dhcp

I have found only one discussion about my problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57710/static-ip-address-shifting-to-192-168-1-251), but not a solution.

I have access to one Debian 7.8.0 amd64 virtual machine (under VMware) and its IP address is gained through DHCP, e.g., `192.168.0.90` (gateway `192.168.0.121`).

To obtain a static IP I configure `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.121
```

Then I run `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` and everything works for hour or two (from `ifconfig` I see `192.168.0.10`). After that time I see with `ifconfig` that my IP has changed automatically to `192.168.0.90` (the old one obtained from DHCP).

Why is this happening?

I tried to execute `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, but it says that `It is deprecated because it may not enable some interfaces...` and my `eth0` goes away and does not show up in `ifconfig` anymore (I need to run `ifup eth0` to bring it up again).

Noone in the network is using `x.x.x.10`.

Comment: `ifconfig -a` to see unenabled interfaces

Comment: Do you have a `dhclient` process running? Please check the result of `ps -ef |grep dhclient`.

Comment: Yes, I have `dhclient` running... Now I will try to kill (or go with remove) to try and I will post the results. Thank you for your comments, people!

Comment: Okay, thank you very much again - killing `dhclient` solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should set your statics IP in the DHCP server or in the router (it could work as DHCP server). Check [this tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/DHCP-Server.html).
There are some considerations about setting a static IP in the client or in the DHCP server. Take a look to [this](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1393495).

Comment: Yes, this surely solves the problem - when IP is set as static in the DHCP server (in the router in my case). Now I am trying by stopping `dhclient` to see what is going to happen when changing the IP from the client. Thank you!