# BeagleBone Black static IP address was changed strangely

Tags: networking

I set up my BBB to static IP address like below:

```
root@beaglebone:/var/log# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.99
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
# Example to keep MAC address between reboots
#hwaddress ether DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE

# WiFi Example
#auto wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
#    wpa-ssid "essid"
#    wpa-psk  "password"

# Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
# ... or on host side, usbnet and random hwaddr
# Note on some boards, usb0 is automaticly setup with an init script
# in that case, to completely disable remove file [run_boot-scripts] from the boot partition
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

And the DNS config of China like below:

```
root@beaglebone:/var/log# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 202.96.128.86
nameserver 202.96.134.33
```

From 2015-12-15 17:04:33 to 2015-12-22 23:03:41, my BBB worked with static IP address 192.168.0.99 well. After that then, my BBB static IP address was changed strangely to 192.168.0.128:

```
root@beaglebone:/var/log# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:5f:b8:e8:b3:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.128/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::d25f:b8ff:fee8:b386/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: usb0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:5c:46:47:5f:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.7.2/30 brd 192.168.7.3 scope global usb0
```

And the `/var/log/messages` like below (Why?):

```
Dec 22 23:03:41 beaglebone kernel: [626417.699238] libphy: 4a101000.mdio:00 - Link is Down
Dec 22 23:03:44 beaglebone kernel: [626420.411322] net eth0: initializing cpsw version 1.12 (0)
Dec 22 23:03:44 beaglebone kernel: [626420.414330] net eth0: phy found : id is : 0x7c0f1
Dec 22 23:03:44 beaglebone kernel: [626420.430487] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Dec 22 23:03:45 beaglebone kernel: [626421.064855] net eth0: initializing cpsw version 1.12 (0)
Dec 22 23:03:45 beaglebone kernel: [626421.067713] net eth0: phy found : id is : 0x7c0f1
Dec 22 23:03:45 beaglebone kernel: [626421.083786] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Dec 22 23:03:47 beaglebone kernel: [626423.075018] libphy: 4a101000.mdio:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
Dec 22 23:03:47 beaglebone kernel: [626423.075152] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Dec 22 23:03:51 beaglebone kernel: [626427.215227] net eth0: initializing cpsw version 1.12 (0)
Dec 22 23:03:51 beaglebone kernel: [626427.218207] net eth0: phy found : id is : 0x7c0f1
Dec 22 23:03:51 beaglebone kernel: [626427.234320] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Dec 22 23:03:51 beaglebone kernel: [626427.637475] net eth0: initializing cpsw version 1.12 (0)
Dec 22 23:03:51 beaglebone kernel: [626427.640382] net eth0: phy found : id is : 0x7c0f1
Dec 22 23:03:51 beaglebone kernel: [626427.656675] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Dec 22 23:03:53 beaglebone kernel: [626429.645608] libphy: 4a101000.mdio:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
Dec 22 23:03:53 beaglebone kernel: [626429.645732] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

My `uname -a` as below:

```
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone47 #1 SMP Fri Apr 11 01:36:09 UTC 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

No one acessed the BeagleBone to change it's ip, **Why the eth0 was down and up around 2015-12-22 23:03:41? Why the static ip address was changed after down and up ?**

PS.

- BeagleBone never rebooted all the time
- I found a similar Q of [Static IP address shifting to 192.168.1.251](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57710/static-ip-address-shifting-to-192-168-1-251), it didn't help
- I checked the command history, no commands was found around 2015-12-22 23:03:41

**UPDATE1** I found that hot-pluged the network cable would call the case mentioned above, and the `dmesg` appeared the same to above, but what was reason? Maybe my interchanger rebooted last night around 2015-12-22 23:03:41, i'm not sured

**UPDATE2**

```
root@beaglebone:~# ps ax | grep dhc
 1132 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/udhcpd -S /etc/udhcpd.conf
10022 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/dhclient -v eth0
20352 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep dhc
```

Comment: could you provide the output of `ps ax | grep dhc` ?

Comment: hi, I had add the `ps ax | grep dhc` to **UPDATE2**, to disable dhcp ?

Comment: Any particular reason for running a DHCP server? As for the dhclient, have this machine booted since you changed it from dhcp to static? It should not be running.

Comment: 1.No particular reason for running a DHCP server, it started up by default, I had disable it. 2.After changed BBB from DHCP to static, I rebooted theBBB. And I did `ps ax | grep dhc` after rebooted, didn't found the dhclient started up.

Comment: I was not explicit, you were running *both* a dhcp client *and* a dhcp server

Answer (score 1):

When network cable was hot-pluged, the dhcp-client changes the static IP address.

Temporary Solution:

```
mv /sbin/dhclient /sbin/dhclient.bak
```

Comment: dont do that, there are better ways. You might need it someday

Comment: As mentioned above, when network cable was hot-pluged, the dhcp-client changes the static IP address. But the reason is still unknown, this is a temporary solution, thank U.

Answer (score 0):

First do:

```
apt-get purge connman dnsmasq*
```

Then you comment out in `/etc/network/interfaces` the `usb0` configuration.
Then change `eth0` to static like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.99
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Do not forget to set the DNS also in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```